# After change its parent Move a div anywhere in the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code. When I drag and drop the '.dragme' div then the parent of this div become change from '#source' to '#drop'. Its ok. But this dragme div's position become fixed in #drop div and I can't move it anywhere in #drop div. How can I do it? Thank you.

HTML:

```
       <div id="source" class="box">
                <div class="dragme">bacon</div>

       </div>
       <div id="drop" class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
     .box { height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #333; }
     .dragme { width:100%; margin:5px; border:1px solid #333; }
```

JavaScript:

```
     $('.dragme').draggable();
     $('#drop, #source').droppable({
     drop:function(e, ui) {
             $(e.target).append($(ui.draggable).detach().css({'top':'', 'left':''}));
     }
     });
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, make sure you use the correct jQuery and jQuery UI versions, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHGqP/.

Comment: Dropped element will move to TOP LEFT corner since you are setting the dropped element position as is " css({'top':'', 'left':''})) ".

Comment: YES. But I want two things. First - I want to change the parent name of div dragme. And I want after change the parent name I can move dragme me div anywhere in new parent div.  In this code in new parent I can't move dragme div.

Comment: Posted a solution for your issue, check and confirm...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/LZv8g/).

```
 $('.dragme').draggable();
     $('#drop, #source').droppable({
         drop:function(e, ui) {
         //$(e.target).append($(ui.draggable).detach().css({'top':'', 'left':''}));  //removed this line.
     }
 });
```

You are setting css `.css({'top':'', 'left':''})`, which is why you cannot move it.

Comment: if i remove that line then div '.dragme' 's parent name not change. I also want to change theparent name. @shaunakde

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the dragged element position to TOP LEFT, that's the reason why you are not able to drag that element to some other position. To avoid this problem, just update the position only if you drag the element out of the parent container.

Updated Code:

```
$('.dragme').draggable();
$('#drop, #source').droppable({
    drop:function(e, ui) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') != $(ui.draggable).parent().attr('id')) {     
            $(e.target).append($(ui.draggable).detach().css({'top':'', 'left':''}));
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHGqP/1/